# How do I animate an alert in ng2-bootstrap in Angular 2?

Tags: animation, angular, ng2-bootstrap

Currently, there are no animations for alerts in ng2-bootstrap in Angular 2. What would be a work around to have the alert fade in and then fadeout on close?